# ipad mini - full content is not visible in 100% view

Tags: html, css, ipad, responsive-design

I am testing one page in my application in mobile-view i.e for ipad-mini in chrome browser. When I view the contents in 50% view, everything looks fine. But when I change to 100% view, some contents from bottom of the page is not visible. Any idea?

I don't have any css for the page just a test page.

[image: In 50% view, I could able to see the bottom of the page.]

[image: In 100% view, I could not able to see the bottom of the page.]